# It is ok to restart the application from a BackgroundWorker?

Tags: vb.net

I have VB.NET application that have a BackgroundWorker that make operations with a MySQL database; and if the BGW crash I want to save the log and restart the application; so it is ok to do something like this?

```
Catch ex As Exception    
    WriteRTBLog(ex.Message, Color.Red)
    WriteRTBLog(ex.StackTrace, Color.DarkRed)
    Application.Restart()
End Try
```

Also, If I restart the application the FormClosing event will be raised?
Because I'm saving the log before closing by using that event.

Comment: If I'm mucking about with data, and sql server blows up at me, blindly trying to continue seems the worst thing I could do.  If you don't know what the exception means and you don't know how to recover, then die.  If you can recover, then do so.  Restarting the whole application seems an odd way to recover.

Comment: Yes, the FormClosing event will be raised.  On the wrong thread if this code lives in the DoWork event handler, that's not good.  There is nothing ever pretty about a user looking helplessly at an app that restarts constantly and immediately crashes again, only thing he can do is reboot the machine.  Or for that matter looking at an app that restarted and did not say why, if there is an RTB at all then it is no longer there.  Lots of reasons to not do this.

Comment: The application works alone, nobody watch it; I need that the application recover by itself. The application works alone one year without any problem but when crash get in a loop and has been working wrong about 3 days until somebody notice it; then I manually close it and work ok again like nothing had happened.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't get what you mean with RTB. Second, Are you saying that the Main Form closes but the BGW will not?

Comment: I don't get what you mean with WriteRTBLog().  Programmers usually mean RichTextBox when they use that acronym.  The UI gadget that is no longer there when you restart so nothing for the user to look at.  If your app isn't looked at for three days in a row then you should not be using a Form at all.  Or use Try/Catch.  A service is the usual choice, they can automatically recover by themselves.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, I got it now, and yes with RTB I mean RichTextBox, I'm sorry I get lost in translation thinking that you was referring to another acronym that I didn't know. The application saves the log every 100K or when the FormClosing is raised so you can read the log with a Worpad. I need the GUI to configure the application and see what is doing time to time. Unfortunately the application crashed in a long weekend and I get noticed on Monday when I get back to work.

Comment: since you app worked fine for a year, and only problem you really mentioned was not noticing for 3 days the problem. Instead of restarting and possibly loop crashing you software for few days, maybe just send group email to ppl that are responsible for it.

Comment: @Claudius Did you mean an automated email from my application?

Comment: Yes, I personally believe that this would be best option in your case. If app was breaking more often then other solutions maybe more suitable. Do not restart app because that doesn't fix anything and may be even harder to catch.

Answer (score 0):

If you call Application.Restart the FormClosing event will be raised from the same thread Restart was called from. So if you're accessing any UI elements you'll need to call Form.Invoke to safely access their properties.

To answer your question though, yes FormClosing will be called. Also, I would wrap those WriteRTBLog calls in their own Try / Catch so if they fail your call to Application.Restart will still be executed.